# How to check platform at runtime

Tags: operating-system, dart, device, flutter, platform

How could I check the **platform** (`Android/iOS`) at runtime?

I’d like to differ my flutter application behaviour if I'm on `Android` rather than I'm on `iOS`.

Like this:

```
_openMap() async {
    // Android
    var url = 'geo:52.32,4.917';
    if (/* i'm on iOS */) {
      url = 'http://maps.apple.com/?ll=52.32,4.917';
    }
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've search a bit on SO and tryed also to Google it but this scenario is not so well indexed and so I think my question and anser could help starting developing on Flutter.

If you have to check the OS or the Platform of your device at runtime you could use the [`Platform` class of `dart.io` library](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-io/Platform-class.html).

```
import 'dart:io'
```

This way you could check in a way like that:

```
_openMap() async {
    // Android
    var url = 'geo:52.32,4.917';
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      // iOS
      url = 'http://maps.apple.com/?ll=52.32,4.917';
    } else if (Platform.isWindows) {
      // TODO - something to do?
    }
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Instead if you also need some deep insight of the device you could use the [`dart device_info package`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/device_info).

There's a good example [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/device_info#-example-tab-).

This way you could also check not only the platform you are running on but also the specific version of OS (`iOS 9, 10.3, 11.x, Lollipop, Jellybean`, etc.) and many others device info.

**UPDATE:**

After Flutter Live 2018 --> Look at this gr8 youtube [video](https://youtu.be/0q2beiiXD98) for Platform Aware Widget and the best way to be compliant with Android and iOS UI from the same codebase.

Answer (score 12):

The recommended way to get the current platform is by using `Theme`.

```
Theme.of(context).platform
```

This way, you could potentially override that value with a custom `Theme` at runtime and see immediately all the changes.

Comment: Oh, good to know! Thank you! It works, I've tested, and for a simple check it requires a bit more coding, but If you need runtime platform changing could be useful. This will improve my question for sure! Thank you +1!

Comment: Anyway, remember that in flutter _everything_ is a widget and that's not a joke. Platform check should be done with widgets too :p

Answer (score 3):

```
import 'dart:io'

String os = Platform.operatingSystem;
```

This is simple way to check platform and also allows a lot of other useful information about the device being used. Link to docs about the [Platform class](https://pub.dev/documentation/platform/latest/platform/Platform-class.html).